# Can't show image with opencv when importing av

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, pyav

When importing the PyAv module, I am unable to show an image with opencv using imshow()

Code without the PyAv module (works as expected)

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("test_image.jpeg")
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Code with the import (doesn't work, just hangs)

```
import cv2
import av

img = cv2.imread("test_image.jpeg")
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

OS: Linux arch 5.18.3-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 09 Jun 2022 16:14:10 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Am I doing something wrong or is this a (un-)known issue?

Comment: not your fault, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21952)

Comment: @berak please post an answer as an answer

Comment: If `cv2.imshow()` doesn't work, you can try using `imshow()` from `matplotlib`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - i dont have a remedy, im only commenting the "am i going insane ?"(no you're not) part of the question

Comment: @Flojomojo. you cannot have both cv2 and av. You can use av and used that too. The av is used gstreamer and ffmpeg and ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is a known issue, mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21952), but it is possible to use the workaround mentioned in the post, here is a quick rundown of how I did it:

NOTE: Do this in a python virtualenv or you might run into problems in the long run

1. Find which version of ffmpeg PyAv uses (currently it's 'ffmpeg-4.4.1-5') and download the exact ffmpeg version [here](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/pyav-ffmpeg/releases)
2. Clone the python-opencv github repo like this `git clone --recursive https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python.git` and run [this script](https://gist.github.com/Flojomojo/658fc691ff55d0217e51a69e31ec98a3) (If this fails, because the path '/tmp/vendor/include doesn't exists, just create it like this `mkdir -p /tmp/vendor/include`)
3. After this is done you can check in the output if the correct ffmpeg version is selected
4. If everything looks correct, you can build it with this command `make -j4` and let it build
5. Finally cd into the `python_loader` folder and run `python3 setup.py develop` and you are done installing :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having to compile from source, you can instead uninstall `pyav` and reinstall it with:

```
pip install av --no-binary av
```

This installs PyAV without FFmpeg and defaults to using your system's already available FFmpeg (likely OpenCV's). This answer was suggested by the people at PyAV [reference](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/978#issuecomment-1121173652). This is assuming that you already have FFmpeg (likely from OpenCV).